# Design Automation put request has Content-Range header missing or malformed

Tags: postman, http-headers, onedrive, autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to upload the [result file of design automation for revit](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step7-post-workitem/)
to sharepoint with the [onedrive rest API.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online#upload-bytes-to-the-upload-session)

In postman I send a post request with a body that tells design automation where and how to upload the result file. "ossuploadURL" is the upload url of sharepoint. unfortunately after the put request, made by design automation, I get a failed upload error. The report states: {"code":"invalidRequest","message":"The Content-Range header is missing or malformed."}

[postman body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrNVH.png)

I have tried without putting headers in the body, different Content-Range, etc. But because i only get: Content-Range missing or malformed i can't see where the problem comes from.

[image: Missing content-range header in report.txt]

Comment: From your postman body, the value for the upload to where is it uploading? I see a mention of OSS but I want to understand better, or is this url a onedrive presigned url to where you want to upload the result. There might be some confusion with the steps so need to understand better what are your trying to achieve.

Comment: I use a post message to Design Automation to tell it how to put a file. Original to a OSS of autodesk. I replaced the OSS autodesk URL with the upload URL for sharepojnt/onedrive. Now i can upload files trough this URL if i put in the Content-Range header (with correct values), and add the file in postman trough the Binary. How to instruct Design automation in this post request to do the same?